# Class this when using Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class

I have a JavaScript Class with some methods.
I also have a link with `onclick` and its function `this` does not point to the Class instance.

Unfortunately it doesn't recognize the inner Class Methods, maybe because `this` is not clear enough.

```
class MyJsClass {
    dummyFunc1() {
        $('#my-link').click(function() {
            console.log('test');
            this.dummyFunc2();
        });
    }
    
    dummyFunc2() {
        console.log('dummyfunc2');
        this.dummyFunc3();
    }
    
    dummyFunc3() {
        console.log('dummyfunc3');
    }
}
```

This doesn't work so I changed it a little bit like this, but it still doesn't work saying `Cannot read property 'dummyFunc3' of undefined`:

```
dummyFunc1() {
    var dummyfunc2 = this.dummyFunc2();
    $('#my-link').click(function() {
        console.log('test');
        dummyfunc2();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside jQuery methods/functions (like `.click()` etc) `this` has its own context of `jQuery` Object instance where `this` is the returned **DOM Element**.
Use instead an [**arrow function** `=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) since it does not have its own bindings to `this` - therefore making `this` refer to the desired **Class instance**:

#### 1. Using Arrow Function

```js
class MyJsClass {
  dummyFunc1() {
    $('#my-link').on("click", (evt) => {
      // If needed use evt.currentTarget instead of this
      // console.dir(evt.currentTarget);   // {}<div id="my-link" />
      this.dummyFunc2(); // this == MyJsClass instance
    });
  }

  dummyFunc2() {
    console.log('dummyfunc2');
    this.dummyFunc3();
  }

  dummyFunc3() {
    console.log('dummyfunc3');
  }
}

const MJSC = new MyJsClass();
MJSC.dummyFunc1();
```

```html
<a id="my-link">CLICK ME</a>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### 2. Using Function.prototype.bind

There's also the **deprecated** [$.proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) if needed:

```js
$('#my-link').on("click", $.proxy(this.dummyFunc2, this));
```

which from jQuery 3.3 can be better used with JS's **[Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)**

```js
class MyJsClass {
  dummyFunc1() {
    $('#my-link').on("click", this.dummyFunc2.bind(this));
  }

  dummyFunc2() {
    console.log('dummyfunc2');
    this.dummyFunc3();
  }

  dummyFunc3() {
    console.log('dummyfunc3');
  }
}

const MJSC = new MyJsClass();
MJSC.dummyFunc1();
```

```html
<a id="my-link">CLICK ME</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```